# Как убрать 0 при загрузке?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

Делаю приложение на реакте и тайпскрипте и при загрузке страницы вместо обычного 'Loading' захотел вставить какой-то реакт-спинер, вроде все ок, работает как надо нопроблема в том что вместе с этим спинером вылазит какой-то 0 в разных частях страницы (только при загрузке, когда приходят данные с сервера он исчезает). Пытался найти его ctrl+shift+f и посмотрел в каждом файле, 0 не нашел. Попытался еще поискать в chrome dev tools, тоже нет. Может это трабл библиотеки ?
Вот сама библиотека - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-spinner
Мой код:

```js
  {loading && (
          <div className="loader">
            <Audio
              height="200"
              width="200"
              color="#ffff"
              ariaLabel="loading"
            />
          </div>
        )}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Покажите, как у вас определена переменная `loading` и как вы ее меняете.

Comment: https://codepen.io/IvaLu/pen/JjZBPKq?editors=0010

Comment: Больше похоже на то, что какойто компонент рендерится и при преобразовании получается 0. Когда данные приходят, видимо перетираете это значение. Посмотрите вот в эту сторону `setProduct` и какое значение лежит в переменной изначально. Допустим у вас `product` изначально имеет значение `{}` или `null`, а вы в рендере без проверки делаете `map`. Ну подебажте приложение. Найдите место, где 0 появляется и посмотрите, что там происходит и какие значения там есть.

Comment: Тоже были такие мысли что при преобразовании вылазит 0 но я убрал библиотеку и 0 пропал, интересно...

Comment: Попробуйте подебажить. Перед каждым открытием/закрытием тега добавьте {'1'} {'2'} примерно так `(  {'1'}<div className="loader"> {'2'} <Audio />  {'3'}` и посмотрите, где вылезет этот 0

Answer (score 0):

Оператору `&&` нужно подавать либо `true`, либо `false`. При других значениях, например `0` вместо `false`, он будет выводить на страницу `0`

```js
const loading = 0;
const loading2 = false;
const loading3 = '';


{loading && <div>Loading...</div>}   // 0
{loading2 && <div>Loading2...</div>} // ''
{loading3 && <div>Loading3...</div>} // ''
```

Как вариант, обернуть `loading` в `Boolean`

```js
{Boolean(loading) && <div>Loading...</div>}
```

Comment: const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false); У меня и был тип данных boolean. Пока не знаю откуда вылазит этот ноль